# Python - passing items from a list as columns for pandas read_csv method

Tags: python, pandas, csv, cgi

I want to convert to a single html file, several values that are inputted from a webform.
This the code I have right now

```
formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
my_file = formData.getvalue("my_filename")
my_col = formData.getlist("column")

print(my_col) #list

for item in my_col:
    csvdata = pandas.read_csv(my_file, usecols=[item])

#cd = csvdata.to_html()
#...
```

Obviously this only converts to html the last item in the list. How can I convert every item in my_col list in a single html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting the last element because you are looping through `my_cols`. You don't need to do that, instead, send the whole `list` `my_cols` to `usecols` as follows and you will get the desired result.

```py
formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
my_file = formData.getvalue("my_filename")
my_col = formData.getlist("column")

print(my_col) #list

csvdata = pandas.read_csv(my_file, usecols=my_col)
```